# How to add this unchangeable text below each slide?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'd like to know how do I add a text below the Powerpoint slides, something similar to what is added to every presentation here:

https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/

I mean this text:
[image]

How can I add it to my presos? I checked in Master slide, but it's not there... not editable at all.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: It's simply a footer.... [Check Powerpoint Help files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-add-headers-and-footers-to-slides-f6c432f1-8e49-41ad-994b-f72736a99aff#:~:text=Show%20footer%20information%20on%20your%20slides&text=Click%20INSERT%20%3E%20Header%20%26%20Footer.,add%20that%20to%20your%20slides.)

Comment: It is not. If I add a footer to those slides, the footer gets atted into the slide, not after the slide

Comment: What do you mean "after the slide". A slide is a slide... there is no "after" there's just the *next* slide. Or.... are you printing **Notes** or **Handouts**? Those have *separate* footers. Please check the link I posted and **all** the topics it lists.

Comment: you are talking about the footer. I am talking about what is after the slide. I will update now the original question with a screenshot of the footer you talk about, and you can see it is in the slide. What I talk about is after the slide.

Comment: Again... there is **no** "after the slide" -- It does **NOT** exist. The ONLY times there may be an image of a slide with content outside that image is if one is viewing Notes or Handouts... in which case they have they *own* footers. And again.. READ the link I posted initially. Specifically.. [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-work-with-handout-masters-ab1ec662-3145-46c8-a2fa-9157d96e83ed) and [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-print-slides-notes-or-handouts-ebbe36f4-5849-4f0c-89b9-a3ee728befa7)

Comment: **All** the info you need is in the help file I have linked to.

Comment: Unfortunately I am receiving the wrong link. The link you posted is about the footer. However the footer is empty. Again, I will update the original question with a creenshot.

Comment: As I said your links are wrong. I managed to make this text disappear by clicking "hide background graphics". Since my goal is not to make this text disappear, but to edit this text in  order to make something similar to my personal designs, I keep this question open

Comment: Your'e merely ONLY looking at the footer.. but clearly have not read about Notes and Handouts... You can lead a horse to water....

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a *background image.*

The text not editable, because it is not the “true” text, but only a part of the image.

So if you want to reach a similar effect, edit your background image in some image editor to insert your “unchangeable text” directly into it.

Answer (score 0):

An image of the text is a good way to have non-editable text on the slide.

You can create this text image *without exiting* PowerPoint.

1. In your PowerPoint presentation create your desired text. Size it and position it accordingly on a blank white slide. (If a blank white layout choice is not available go to your master slides and create one so you can choose it from the Layout pull down menu. Also, make sure it does not have any of those 'placeholder' container frames on it.)
2. Now go to File and select Save As. Determine where this file will be saved (like 'Desktop'). Choose JPEG format (or some other image file format). Provide a name and click Save.
3. An alert panel will appear and ask you if you want save "All Slides" or "Just This One". Choose the "Just This One" button. You will be taken back to your presentation.
4. Now in your presentation go to Insert and choose Pictures. The Insert Picture window appears. Go find and select the picture of your text you just saved. Click the Insert button. The picture of your text will be placed on your slide. The picture is the same dimensions as your working slide and will cover the entire slide. This will position your non-editable text exactly where you created it.
5. Use the image crop tool and crop the image down to only the desired text. Cut and paste the image onto whatever master slides you want it to appear on.

I hope this helps.

Best of luck,

Pete

Answer (score 0):

It's a text box. Just go to View > Master Views > Slide Master. Then you can edit that text box, delete, or insert another text box.